# A fast way to create a list with $A_i\cdot B_i^{-1}\cdot C_i$ in each component

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, function-construction

Let us suppose I have to do the following computation $A_i\cdot B_i^{-1}\cdot C_i$, where $A_i,B_i,C_i$ are conformable matrices(dim=$50\times 50$).

For that, I have 3 lists, each of size 1 by 10,000 , where in list $A$, each component is a matrix $A_i$, and similarly for list $B$, we have $B_i^{-1}$, and for $C$.

1. I thought of doing a ParallelTable. Or should I go for a loop? Is
   there a faster way to create a list where each component is
   $A_i\cdot B_i^{-1}\cdot C_i$? Is there a way to vectorize this ?
2. What if I do a huge loop where I build the lists A,B and C, and as I build them, I also calculate $A_i\cdot B_i^{-1}\cdot C_i$?

If this question is too broad, or really needs a working example, tell me, don't just vote to close. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few possibilities:

```
n = 10000;
m = 50;
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, m, m}];
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, m, m}];
c = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, m, m}];

result = MapThread[#1.LinearSolve[#2, #3] &, {a, b, c}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
result2 = Table[a[[i]].LinearSolve[b[[i]], c[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[a]}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

DistributeDefinitions[a, b, c]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
result3 = ParallelTable[a[[i]].LinearSolve[b[[i]], c[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[a]}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

On my Haswell Quad Core CPU, this produces the following timings:

> 1.29189
>
> 3.87935
>
> 6.70797
>
> 0.454736

This highlights that moving all the data between several core is the major bottleneck here. So, in total, `MapTread` seems to be the better option. In fact, this makes me wonder whether `MapTread` *is* parallelized (the documentation does not state that).

I am currently not aware of a better way to parallelize this. Unfortunately, `Compile` with options `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}` and `Parallelization -> True` does *not* work because `LinearSolve` cannot be compiled and thus needs calls to `MainEvaluate` which makes parallelization inpossible.

Comment: Henrik, thank you for your answer. I still have a few questions. Why is there a need for DistributeDefinitions? Couldn't you just use ParallelTable?

Comment: Oh, you _can_ use `ParallelTable` directly, at least in newer version of _Mathematica_. When you run the code `result3 = ParallelTable[...]` for the first time, it will take around 7 seconds; when you do it for the second time (with the same definitions of `a`, `b`, and `c`), it will take only `0.45` seonds.That puzzled me quite a lot (this is why the first version of my post states that `ParallelTable` were faster). So  I decided to make `DistributeDefinitions` explicit in order to show that it is the bottleneck here.

Comment: Ah... I get it now! Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Henrik, I've been using LInearSolve, instead of inverting the matrices B... Let's assume that $A_i=C_i^T$ and B is symmetric positive definite, then $C_i^TB^{-1}C_i$ should give a symmetric positive definite matrix. However, when I do SymmetricMatrixQ I may get False. When I do PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ I always get True...

Comment: That's due to rounding errors. When `B` is ill-conditioned, this may be come quite severe. Actually, I expected that using `Method -> "Cholesky"` in `LinearSolve` would improve upon that but to no avail... =/

Comment: Yes, I used all methods, and Cholesky was the best one, but didn't solve the problem. These rounding errors seemed strange. Even for 10 by 10 matrices which don't give badly-conditioned warnings. I've opened this new question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191473/using-linearsolve-instead-of-inverse