# Using LinearSolve instead of Inverse does not give a good enough precision

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, precision-and-accuracy

If I want to calculate $B^{-1}A$, then instead of using `Inverse`, I should in theory just be able to use `LinearSolve[B,A]`.

Now if I have $B$ is positive definite and symmetric, then $A^TB^{-1}A$ should also be PD and Symmetric. But it's not...

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
n = 1000;
m = 10;
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, m, m}];
b = RandomVariate[WishartMatrixDistribution[11, IdentityMatrix[10]], 
   n];
result = ParallelTable[
   a[[i]].LinearSolve[b[[i]], Transpose[a[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[a]}];
```

And then I get

```
In[323]:= Total[PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ result]
Total[SymmetricMatrixQ /@ result]

Out[323]= 1000 True

Out[324]= 388 False + 612 True
```

This is a precision problem. If I use Inverse the problem worsens.

However, this seems like something that could have been corrected... Or is it something very difficult to do? I don't get any warning about badly-conditioned matrices.

Comment: What do you get with `Total[SymmetricMatrixQ[#, Tolerance -> 1*^-10] & /@ result]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I get 1000 True. The problem is that other in-built functions will 'complain'. For example, if I use the matrices above as covariance matrices in MultinormalDistribution, I get an error message. And I guess it's not the only one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `CholeskyDecomposition` explicitly not only seems to remove the problem, it is also faster: Moreover, this gets rid of one of the matrix-matrix multiplications and, probably more important, it requires onle one triangular matrix solve instead of two.

Notice also that I cast the matrix-matrix products in a way that `Transpose[#].# &` is applied last. This ensures that the resulting matrix is numerically symmetric and positive (semi-)definite.

```
n = 1000;
m = 50;
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, m, m}];
b = RandomVariate[WishartMatrixDistribution[m + 1, IdentityMatrix[m]],
    n];

result = Table[
    a[[i]].LinearSolve[b[[i]], Transpose[a[[i]]]], {i, 1, 
     Length[a]}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
result2 = Table[
    With[{L = Transpose[CholeskyDecomposition[b[[i]]]]},
     Transpose[#].# &[LinearSolve[L, Transpose[a[[i]]]]]
     ], {i, 1, Length[a]}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

Total[SymmetricMatrixQ /@ result]
Total[SymmetricMatrixQ /@ result2]
```

> 0.437883
>
> 0.19313
>
> 529 False + 471 True
>
> 1000 True

Beware that `CholeskyDecomposition` *does not apply pivoting* which may also cause accuracy problems when small entries appear on the main diagonal.

Comment: I get  `Total[SymmetricMatrixQ /@ result2]` --> `163 False + 837 True`, the reverse of what you're showing, if I start with `SeedRandom[1]`.

Comment: If I use `LinearSolve[b[[i]], Transpose[a[[i]]], Method -> "Cholesky"]` in the OP's code, then I get `1000 True`...

Comment: Huh, that is indeed weird. Version 11.3 for macOS delivers `1000 True` also for `SeedRandom[1]`...

Comment: @MichaelE2, when I use Method -> Cholesky, I don't get that!! I still get many Falses... I'm using Windows 7, with Mathematica Version 11.0.1

Comment: That weird. I'm using V11.3 (but the early one) on MacOS, too: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yfSnf.png

Comment: Mine is from March 7, 2018. Hm. Might be due to an update. It make me feel uncomportable that `Transpose[#].# &` might not able to produce symmetric matrices...

Answer (score 5):

The problem is rounding error.  The option `Tolerance` is one way *Mathematica* lets you deal with it in some functions.

```
SeedRandom[0];
n = 1000;
m = 10;
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, m, m}];
b = RandomVariate[WishartMatrixDistribution[11, IdentityMatrix[10]], n];
result = Table[a[[i]].LinearSolve[b[[i]], Transpose[a[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[a]}];

Total[PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ result]
Total[SymmetricMatrixQ[#, Tolerance -> 1*^-10] & /@ result]
(*
  1000 True
  1000 True
*)
```

Here's why `1*^-10` is about the right tolerance:

```
ListPlot[#, PlotLabel -> Max[#]] &[
 $MachineEpsilon*Through[(LinearSolve /@ b)["ConditionNumber"]]
 ]
```

[image]

The condition number estimates the relative loss of precision due to `LinearSolve`.  The maximum absolute value of the entries of the matrices `b` are near `1`, so `$MachineEpsilon` is the right number to use to multiply the condition number.  There is further rounding error in the matrix multiplication, so the tolerance needs to be a little greater than the estimated maximum error shown in the plot label above.