# Can we compile this function/distribution?

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

I would like to compile this function to make it faster:

```
logMultinormalDens2[x_, mean_, var2_] := Module[{},        
   t = 0.5*
     Flatten[(x - mean)].LinearSolve[var2, Flatten[(x - mean)], 
       Method -> "Cholesky"];
   (*Flatten - The LinearSolve receives only {} not {{}}*)

   det = Det[2*Pi*var2]^(0.5);

   -t - Log[det]

   ];
```

I've tried writing `:=Compile[{},Module[(...)];];`
but it takes the same time to evaluate as before.
I've also tried using `Block`, and it didn't improve much either...

Edit: This function is called at least 300000 times (for each Time period. I want to use it several periods). Each time this distribution is called, we use a different mean and var2 (using some sum and matrix multiplication) from some other lists. Ex: mean_i = A_i+B_i, where A_i and B_i are in some other lists. var2 is a $3\times 3$ matrix

Comment: No, there is in general no point in compiling `LinearSolve` since its backend consists already of compiled libraries. Maybe the calling overhead is reduces a bit if you call the compiled function many times, but usually the difference is negligible.

Comment: But tell me, how large is the matrix `var2`? Also, it is relevant to know how the data looks like onto which you want to apply the function. Maybe there is some structure (e.g., redundance) that can be exploited to achieve a speed-up.

Comment: A sample usage of the function is always helpful to me, to understand how you intend to use it (and how to answer your answer).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Hi Henrik, the var2 is a $3\times 3$ matrix. This function is called at least 15000 times(*20 by parallelization * number of periods). Each time this distribution is called, we use a different mean and var2 (using some sum and matrix multiplication) from some other lists. Ex: mean_i = A_i+B_i, where A_i and B_i are in some other lists

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing Hi, I've added some more information. If you need more, please tell me. Thanks

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Do you know apriorily that the matrices `var2` are well-conditioned?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I'm not sure. So far, for the several smaller simulations I've done (10 000 calls), I haven't received a single warning of ill-conditioned matrices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One may simply write out the matrix inverses symbolically (by Cramer's formula) and compile the resulting expression.

For dimension 3, Cramer's formula is not *that* inefficient. And if we know that the matrices are not too badly conditioned, that the instability (for which Cramer's formula is also infamous) are not that severe.

```
clogMultinormalDens2 = 
  Block[{XX, X, MM, M, ΣΣ, Σ, adjunct, det, c},
   XX = Table[Compile`GetElement[X, i], {i, 1, 3}];
   MM = Table[Compile`GetElement[M, i], {i, 1, 3}];
   ΣΣ = Table[Compile`GetElement[Σ, i, j], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];
   det = Det[ΣΣ];
   c = 3. Log[2. Pi];
   adjunct = Inverse[ΣΣ] det;

   With[{code = -0.5 (((XX - MM).adjunct.(XX - MM))/det + c + Log[det])}, 
    Compile[{{X, _Real, 1}, {M, _Real, 1}, {Σ, _Real, 2}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
     Parallelization -> True,
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

Createing some test data. Adding a small multiple of the identity matrix ensures that the matrices are well-conditioned.

```
n = 100000;
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}];
μ = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}];
A = Plus[
   0.1 ConstantArray[IdentityMatrix[3, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision], n],
   Map[#\[Transpose].# &, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3, 3}]]
   ];
```

Now a test run:

```
a = MapThread[logMultinormalDens2, {x, μ, A}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
b = clogMultinormalDens2[x, μ, A]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[1 - b/a]]
Max[Abs[b - a]]
```

> 1.76667
>
> 0.005171
>
> 1.24345*10^-14
>
> 2.16716*10^-13

More than 300 times faster and, at least in this case, with acceptable relative and absolute errors.

Comment: Henrik, many thanks. I'm going to have to study your answer =D it's full of things I don't know. I'll get in touch later on. ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to ask me if anything is unclear.

Comment: Hi Henrik, I've just had some time, and I have some questions.
1 - What does Compile`GetElement do exactly? I've tried searching through the mathematica documentation, but neither ' nor GetElement are in it.

(to be continued)

Comment: 2 - From a previous question of mine, we(it was also your answer, incidentally =D https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191421/a-fast-way-to-create-a-list-with-a-i-cdot-b-i-1-cdot-c-i-in-each-component) concluded that if I had to use a different x, mean and var2, we should use something similar to MapThread. How would we do that for this answer? This should increase the expected computing time for your procedure...

Comment: 3 - In the last compile, in the type declaration, why do we have a 2 for sigma and a 1 for all the others?

[End of doubts]

Comment: ``Compile`GetElement`` is a quicker version of `Part`. Together with `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"`, this causes that in the created C code, it is not checked every time whether a read operation into an array is out of bounds. That's why it is quicker. But that demands the programmer to take care of some things. For example, we should not call `clogMultinormalDens2` with arrays `X`, `M`, and `Σ` with dimensions smaller than `{3}`, `{3,3}`, and `{3,3}`. Otherwise, `clogMultinormalDens2 ` will read from positions in memory where values of some other data field are stored.

Comment: If this feels cheesy to you, you may replace ``Compile`GetElement`` also by `Indexed` or `Part`.

Comment: `clogMultinormalDens2 ` has the option `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}`, so the `MapThread` is built-in: it just threads over lists. But since `logMultinormalDens2` knows the tensor rank of its arguments, this threading works lightly different as for usual functions with the attribute `Listable`.

Comment: `{M, _Real, 1}` declares that `M` is supposed to be a vector and `{Σ, _Real, 2}` declares that `Σ` is supposed to be a matrix. So the number at the third positions declares the tansor rank of the argument.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Many thanks Henrik! +1 ;)

Comment: You're welcome!